# Passar valores (radio) de um HTML para outro

Tags: javascript, html

Está é minha primeira vez por aqui, espero estar fazendo tudo certo.

Minha pergunta é a seguinte, tenho uma página com um questionário de 4 perguntas, sendo que 3 destas a resposta é dada via `'radio'` e o outro via `'select'`.

Em outra página html tenho que passar as respostas dadas na página anterior para essa, exibindo na tela as escolhas feitas.

Gostaria de saber como realizar essa tarefa sem o uso de PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer o seguinte, pegando as respostas das perguntas e enviar para a outra página como parâmetro após o `?`:

```
outra_pagina.html?abcd
```

Onde `abcd` seriam as alternativas escolhidas.

Na *outra página* você captura esse parâmetro e faz um laço `for` concatenando os resultados e em seguida joga para dentro de uma `div`.

**Código da primeira página com as perguntas:**

```
Pergunta 1:
<br />
a) <input type="radio" name="perg1" value="a">
<br />
b) <input type="radio" name="perg1" value="b">
<br />
c) <input type="radio" name="perg1" value="c">

<br /><br />

Pergunta 2:
<br />
a) <input type="radio" name="perg2" value="a">
<br />
b) <input type="radio" name="perg2" value="b">
<br />
c) <input type="radio" name="perg2" value="c">

<br /><br />

Pergunta 3:
<br />
a) <input type="radio" name="perg3" value="a">
<br />
b) <input type="radio" name="perg3" value="b">
<br />
c) <input type="radio" name="perg3" value="c">

<br /><br />

Pergunta 4:
<br />
<select name="perg4">
   <option value="">Selecione...</option>
   <option value="a">a</option>
   <option value="b">b</option>
   <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<br /><br />

<button onclick="enviar()">Enviar</button>
<script>
function enviar(){

   var perg1_val = document.querySelector("input[name='perg1']:checked"),
       perg2_val = document.querySelector("input[name='perg2']:checked"),
       perg3_val = document.querySelector("input[name='perg3']:checked"),
       perg4_val = document.querySelector("select[name='perg4']").value;

   if(perg1_val && perg2_val && perg3_val && perg4_val != ''){

      location.href = "outra_pagina.html?"
      + perg1_val.value
      + perg2_val.value
      + perg3_val.value
      + perg4_val;

   }else{
      alert("Responda todas as perguntas");
   }

}
</script>
```

**Código da *outra página*:**

```
<div id="respostas">
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   var url_ = location.href,
      param = url_.substring(url_.lastIndexOf("?")+1, url_.length),
      resps = '';

   for(var x=0; x<param.length; x++){
      resps += "Pergunta "+(x+1)+": resposta <b>"+param[x]+"</b><br />";
   }

   document.querySelector("#respostas").innerHTML = resps;

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Algumas alternativas estão disponíveis:

1. Converta seu formulário para uma solicitação GET, resultando em um URL longo e feio
2. Use cookies
3. Use HTML5 local storage

**Com local storage**

```
Pergunta 1:
<br />
a) <input type="radio" name="perg1" value="a">
<br />
b) <input type="radio" name="perg1" value="b">
<br />
c) <input type="radio" name="perg1" value="c">

<br /><br />

Pergunta 2:
<br />
a) <input type="radio" name="perg2" value="a">
<br />
b) <input type="radio" name="perg2" value="b">
<br />
c) <input type="radio" name="perg2" value="c">

<br /><br />

Pergunta 3:
<br />
a) <input type="radio" name="perg3" value="a">
<br />
b) <input type="radio" name="perg3" value="b">
<br />
c) <input type="radio" name="perg3" value="c">

<br /><br />

Pergunta 4:
<br />
<select name="perg4">
   <option value="">Selecione...</option>
   <option value="a">a</option>
   <option value="b">b</option>
   <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<br /><br />

<button onclick="enviar()">Enviar</button>


<script>
function enviar(){


   var perg1_val = document.querySelector("input[name='perg1']:checked"),
       perg2_val = document.querySelector("input[name='perg2']:checked"),
       perg3_val = document.querySelector("input[name='perg3']:checked"),
       perg4_val = document.querySelector("select[name='perg4']").value;

   if(perg1_val && perg2_val && perg3_val && perg4_val != ''){

      var respostas = perg1_val.value+","+perg2_val.value+","+perg3_val.value+","+perg4_val;

      localStorage.setItem("respostas", respostas);

      location.href = "outra_pagina.html";

   }else{
      alert("Responda todas as perguntas");
   }

}
</script>
```

**outra_pagina.html**

```
<script language="javascript">

var respostas = localStorage.getItem("respostas");

document.write (respostas);

</script>
```